# TYPO3 Prefill text field in my own extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I need to save the IP address of a user who fills out my form.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
 'userip' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myExtension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myextension_domain_model_myextension.userip',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim',
            'default' => '12345'.$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
        ]
    ],
```

But that doesn't work. What would be the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] is not available in TCA cause this is BE related stuff.

Use the setter from the model, setUserip($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]), in your createAction() or initializeCreateAction() to save the value in DB.